# The Scroll bar is not wrapped in the scrollable content area in jQuery mobile1.4.0

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscroll, jquery-mobile-listview

In my jQuery mobile app for android , I have  a long list view inside a popup , I have used iscroll because overflow:auto is not working on  android 2.3.6 , and scrolling now is working ok on all android devices after using iscroll , but the problem is that the scroll bar  starts from the header of the popup  to the end of the popup ( along the popup height) not the list view height "popup content"  although i applied the iscroll to the div that contains the listview. How can I fix this problem and make the scroll appears a long the list height? please help me

This is the iscroll.js that i use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsDA5/1/)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/iscroll.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">Main</div>
<div data-role="content"> 
<a href="" data-rel="popup" id="Btn1" class="ui-btn  ui-corner-all" data-   inline="true">Show Popup</a>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="MyPOPUP" data-position-to="window" data-corners="false" data-  overlay-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a">

    <div style="text-align:center;float:center;padding-top:11px;">
    <font size="6px" color="white">Countries</font>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="scrollContent" class="content" data-role="content" style="background-color: white;">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="countrieslist" style="margin: 0 !important;">

    </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS code

```
$(document).on( 'pagecreate', '#index',function(){

   var  scrollObj;
// to make the popup  take the screen width ,height 
    var window_Width = $( window ).width();
    var window_Height = $(window).height();

 $('#MyPOPUP').css('width', window_Width-30 );
 $('#scrollContent').css('width', window_Width-30 );

     $('#MyPOPUP').css('height', window_Height-(window_Height/4) );

     $('#scrollContent').css('height', window_Height-(window_Height/4)-87 );


scrollObj = new iScroll('scrollContent', { vScrollbar: true,      hScrollbar:false,fixedScrollbar : true,momentum: true});


    for(var i=1;i<=50;i++) {
    $('#countrieslist').append('<li id="'+i+'"><a href="#" style="background:transparent  !important;"><font>Country' + i +'</font></a></li>');                
     }
    $('#countrieslist').listview('refresh');

    setTimeout(function () {
    scrollObj.refresh();
  }, 0);



     $('#Btn1').on('click', function(){ 
           $(this).attr('href','#MyPOPUP');    
     });

    $('#countrieslist').on('click','li', function() {

         selected_elem =  $(this).attr('id');
         console.log('you selected' + selected_elem);
        $('#MyPOPUP').popup('close');
     });
});
```

CSS

```
#scrollContent{

   padding: 0 !important;

}
```

Comment: What are the styles you have for .content class?

Comment: @Faizul HasanThanks you have guided me to the problem cause , once I removed this class , the problem solved  and the scroll  is working perfect now

Comment: @Faizul HasanTheir is  a  weird thing ,  the scroll is working  for one time when I open the page that contais this popup   , then when i navigate between the app pages and then back to the popup page the scroll become not working !! why this happens ? I don't know what to do  ?  Please can you help me ??